# Apache port and url

Tags: apache, port, virtualhost

I want to have several sites on my local machine, associated to specific port in my apache configuration. I don't even know if what I want is possible to do, or if I have the good way of thinking. May be I need other tools, so please, can you explain me ?

I have my dev machine with several site working on it, in my hosts file I put:

```
127.0.0.1        local.site1.com
127.0.0.1        local.site2.com
```

In appache configuration, I have these virtual hosts:

```
Listen 8081
Listen 8082

<VirtualHost *:8081>
  ServerName local.site1.com
  ServerAlias local.site1.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/site1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8082>
  ServerName local.site2.com
  ServerAlias local.site2.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/site2"
</VirtualHost>
```

Do you know what should I do to have ?

- http://local.site1.com that goes **automatically** and **only** to port 8081
- http://local.site2.com that goes **automatically** and **only** to port 8082

Now, my configuration looks useless, because http://local.site1.com opens port 80, and http://local.site2.com:8081 goes to site1.

Comment: [Install mod_proxy and forward from 80 to the ports u need to.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Comment: mod_proxy looks pretty general, can you advice what kind of directive I should use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want them running on different ports? You don't need to do that to get what you want.

You can use NameVirtualHosts and run both sites on the same port, and the server will serve the correct site based on the domain name used in your browser.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Example

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName local.site1.com
  ServerAlias local.site1.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/site1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName local.site2.com
  ServerAlias local.site2.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/site2"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you, I didn't know about NameVirtualHost, and indeed, I didn't need different ports.